# How to run local tests when using Heroku Connect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, salesforce

In a Heroku application I'm using the Connect add-on to synchronize Salesforce tables in a salesforce schema in my database.

I created models in my project to instantiate records from this salesforce schema. Here is an example:

```
class Salesforce::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "salesforce.account"
end
```

Everything works fine on Heroku. However my local database populated from migrations does obviously not contain the salesforce tables. Hence it is not possible for me to conceive any test referencing my Salesforce model.

What is the classic way to handle this kind of problem? Thanks!

Comment: I have not actually used Connect but I can't really see why you would not use Rails migrations to setup the salesforce tables schema just like you would for any table which holds normalized data from an external source. Then you would just test it with factories or fixture data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've dealt with this is to maintain a schema definition for local development that mimics the Heroku Connect created schema.  To verify this I have a staging app on Heroku that uses Heroku Connect.  That way I can make sure things work / the schemas are the same before I go to prod.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you have an automated way to get the Heroku Connect schema ? I tried db:schema:dump on a database pulled from Heroku, but Salesforce schema is not dumped.

Comment: That should work but you'll need to make sure you specify the `salesforce` schema since Connect uses a different one than the default.

Comment: I succeeded to dump both schema (public and salesforce) by using structure.sql instead of schema.db. Thanks !